# Can't change submenu style like i want

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, submenu

I have a wordpress site and this is my theme's sub menu.

MY SUB MENU:

[image]

I want to change my sub menu like:

APPLE'S SUB MENU:

[image]

this.

Is it possible to changing css/html to my sub menu to evolve this menu ?
Or am i wasting my effort.
If it is possible can u lead me the way for doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

With css you can give your parent element, which in this case is the menu, a value of `display: table`. And what makes the menu elements line up side by side like in the Apple example is adding a value of `display: table-cell` to the menu elements. That should make it happen but make sure you have correct class-names in the custom css or otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Firts thing i need to do before table-cell, when i click to main menu, submenu should open down and stick there until i click another menu item, just like apple . But my header's css classes are too complicated i wish i could show you